# How to create and add elements to an array of array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

What is the proper way of creating and adding elements to an array of array of hashes?

Here's something similar to what I want, initializing the `result` variable:

```
col1.each_with_index do |ob1,index1|
  col2.each_with_index do |ob2,index2|
    col3.each do |ob3|
      result[index1][index2][ob3.id] = Obj.new(ob1.att, ob2.att, ob3.att)
    end
  end
end
```

I should be able to access `result` like:

```
result[1][2][1031]
```

where 1031 is an id, and the others are indexes from 0..n. It should return an instance of `Obj`.

Comment: please, write the instances both your array and expecting result

Comment: How many elements do you need at each level?

Comment: col1, col2 and col3 are of dynamic sizes, so result should be the same.

Comment: also, I may be wrong with how I'm assigning elements to result, this is just to explain what I want.

Comment: An empty array won't have any depth to it, so you need to pick at least a minimal size for this structure.

Answer (score 3):

Just out of curiosity, the lazy instantiated object, built on top of [`Hash#default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc):

```
result = Hash.new { |h1, k1|
  (0...col1.size) === k1 ? h1[k1] = Hash.new { |h2, k2|
    (0...col2.size) === k2 ? h2[k2] = Hash.new { |h3, k3|
      o3 = col3.detect { |o| o.id == k3 }
      o3 ? h3[k3] = Obj.new(col1[k1].att, col2[k2].att, o3.att) : nil
    } : nil
  } : nil
}
```

*Disclamer:* please do not use this coding style in production. The example is given in demonstration purposes only.

Comment: There's a reason I recommend people avoid chaining ternary operators and this is a sterling example of why. This is one crazy intense nugget of code.

Comment: @tadman Have you noticed I put “just out of curiosity” disclamer at the very top of the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure that's a license to get crazy. This is a complicated thing to throw at someone just getting started in Ruby.

Comment: @CarySwoveland If you're ignoring the experience level of the person asking the question, why would anyone even bother asking a question here? I don't think it's unreasonable to keep it simple for those just getting started. I doubt most people, looking at this code, would be able to tell you exactly what it does without five minutes of serious consideration.

Comment: @tadman, questions will keep coming because, as here, others will answer the question in a way that can be understood by the OP. I doubt that mudsie would have given his answer had it been the first. Suppose the OP and 19 others read this answer. It might not be understood by the OP and (say) 7 others, and of the remaining 12, 7 may not learn anything, but if 5 readers learn something new, is that not a good thing?

Comment: It's *perhaps* a good thing, but code like this is why we have things like [Code Climate](https://codeclimate.com). Simple code is maintainable code, and maintainable is better than confusing. I'd hate to have to debug this if something was going wrong. The educational value of this is dubious at best, it may as well be a black box that encourages Cargo Cult Programming.

Comment: Isn't this `do` here `|h3, k3| do` excess?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko indeed, thanks for being captious, removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
result = []
[1,3,5].each_with_index do |ob1,index1|
  [2,4,6].each_with_index do |ob2,index2|
    [{ id: 1000 }, { id: 10000 }, { id: 10000 }].each do |ob3|
      result[index1] = result[index1] || []
      result[index1][index2] = result[index1][index2] || {}
      result[index1][index2][ob3[:id]] = { a: ob1, b: ob2, c: ob3 }
    end
  end
end
```

I changed your `.id` to `[:id]` here for simplicity.  The idea is to set it to itself if what you want already exists, or else initialize it to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an array of arrays of arrays, you can use the following syntax:

```
2.3.0 :001 > Array.new(2) { Array.new(3) }
 => [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]

# Or, 3 level deep array
2.3.0 :002 > Array.new(2) { Array.new(3) { Array.new(4) } }
 => [[[nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil]], [[nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil]]]
```

Consider also using Hash'es.

Comment: Changing the third level to `{ }` or `Hash.new` for clarity would be what they were asking for.

Comment: So, translating to my example it would be: `result = Array.new(col1.size) { Array.new(col2.size) { Hash.new(col3.size) } }` ? That correct? @tadman

Comment: That creates a Hash with a default value of `col3.size`, which makes no sense. Omit that argument.